# How to install wps geoserver extension to Centos6.5

Tags: geoserver, wps, boundless-suite, centos

I installed OpenGeo Suit on CentOS 6.5 and the version of geoserver is 2.5-SNAPSHOT.
I made a `yum update` and the version of OpenGeo Suit is 4.1, geoserver version remain  2.5-SNAPSHOT.

I would like to install wps extension but I am a very new centos user and don't know the path to put the extensions files.
I also want to ask about the path to put GED SDI Portal v.3 to work in my local-host.

Answer (score 2):

The wps module is a separate package on Linux. `yum install geoserver-wps` should do it.